# Determining whether a token is primary or impersonation using win32api?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, token

Let's say I have a handle the following code

```py
pid = 1234
pHandle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,pywintypes.FALSE,pid)
tHandle = win32security.OpenProcessToken(pHandle,win32con.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED)
```

How would I determine if the process token was a primary or impersonation token?

Comment: process token is always primary token. here nothing to determine. the thread token is always (if exist) impersonation token

Comment: GetTokenInformation(TokenType)

Comment: Thanks for helping. Both of these answers are acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

process token is always primary token. so here nothing to determine. the thread token is always (if exist) impersonation token. so when you open process or thread token - you already know it type. all api which return token - return known from begin token type. only case, when you need determine token type (which is unknown ) - you enumerate process handles and try check token handles.
for this you need use [`GetTokenInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation) with [`TokenType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ne-winnt-token_type), but really this is rare case, when you can need this. only for some debug utility.

demo code on *c/c++*

```
ULONG GetTokenType(_In_ HANDLE hToken, _Out_ PTOKEN_TYPE ptp)
{
    ULONG cb;
    return GetTokenInformation(hToken, ::TokenType, ptp, 
        sizeof(TOKEN_TYPE), &cb) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

void DemT()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        TOKEN_TYPE tp;
        // we already know that token is primary
        if (GetTokenType(hToken, &tp) != NOERROR || tp != TokenPrimary)
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }
        
        CloseHandle(hToken);

        if (0 <= NtImpersonateAnonymousToken(GetCurrentThread()))
        {
            if (OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_QUERY, TRUE, &hToken))
            {
                // we already know that token is impersonating
                if (GetTokenType(hToken, &tp) != NOERROR || tp != TokenImpersonation)
                {
                    __debugbreak();
                }

                CloseHandle(hToken);
            }

            SetThreadToken(0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```